# List services with port numbers

Tags: centos, ps, netstat

I would like to list all installed services (especially running) with their port numbers, where they are assigned. Could you be so glad and help me with this command?

Comment: `sudo netstat -lntup` or `sudo lsof`

Comment: Also, check `/etc/services` to get the list of standard port numbers.